# Remove useless hypothesis from context

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Sometimes I have a hypothesis in my proof context that I've used already, and now I know I won't need it anymore. In order to keep my context tidy while I work on the proof, I'd like to remove this hypothesis. Is there a tactic to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [clear](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.clear) tactic:

Before:

```
1 goal
  
  stuff ...
  H : T
  ============================
  goal
```

```
clear H.
```

After:

```
1 goal
  
  stuff ...
  ============================
  goal
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the SSReflect proof language, you can clear an hypothesis `H` by using the `{H}` notation. This can be done inline after many tactics such as `move` or `rewrite`, as in:

```
rewrite foo bar => {H}
```